# Why do many Drupal themes markup images with typeof="foaf:Image" attribute?

Tags: media, theming

Does this attribute simply enhance semantics?

Comment: read about RDF - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework

Comment: Ok, so it describes the resource as an image using a vocabulary defined within the Resource Description Framework (RDF).

Comment: Probably the best description of the foaf vocabulary can be found here: http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec and yes, it is to enhance/describe the Semantic Web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it’s about semantics of your content. That way, your page/content is part of the [Semantic Web](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web).

#### **Background**

The `typeof` attribute is defined by [RDFa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa).
RDFa is a syntax to embed [RDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework) in markup languages like HTML.

The value `foaf:Image` (most likely) refers to the [Friend of a Friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOAF_%28ontology%29) vocabulary/ontology. The namespace `foaf:` typically stands for the URI of that vocabulary (`http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`), so the value is actually the URI `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Image`.

`http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Image` is a *class*. It’s (= what it means) documented here: http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_Image.

Comment: So would I be right in thinking this attribute should only be used on images of people? The Friend of a Friend ontology seems very focused on people.

Comment: @Andrew: While FOAF’s main focus might be describing persons, it’s not their only use case. If the `Image` is used as object in a triple with the [`img` property](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_img), then yes, the subject would be `Person` (see "Range" and "Domain" in the definition of the property). But if it would be used with the [`depiction` property](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_depiction), the subject could be a [`Thing`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_Thing) aka. "universal class of all things" (= *anything*).

Comment: @Andrew: And: Classes like FOAF’s `Image` could also be reused by other vocabularies, in totally different contexts. The only that thing matters is the [definition](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_Image), where it only says: It’s an image, and this class is a subclass of [`Document`](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_Document).

Comment: @unor, so Drupal does not give either a `foaf:img` nor a `foaf:depiction` property. So, is this actually an incorrect or simply incomplete implementation?  You say all that matters is `foaf:Image` definition; matters to who/what?

Comment: @JamesWilson: With "matters" I meant: when using the class `foaf:Image`, no matter in which context, you should follow its definition. -- Without specifying a *property* (like `foaf:img` or `foaf:depiction`), it simply means: "This is an `foaf:Image`." So such markup is not incorrect nor incomplete (well, it depends on what you want to convey).

Comment: Aren't all `<img>`s images, by definition? I'm struggling to see what value applying `typeof="foaf:image"` to all <img> tags adds to the semantic web. Can you give a practical example of an application (real or hypothetical) that usefully processes images tagged `typeof="foaf:image"` and can't work with images without it (or which usefully discriminates between images with and without `typeof="foaf:image"`)?

Comment: @user568458: Specifying that something is a `foaf:Image` allows you to specify data *about* this *something*: it sets the scope for any properties (i.e., `property` attributes) that are descendants of the element with the `foaf:Image` type (which doesn’t have to be an actual `img` element, or even a digital image at all). And if you give this image a URI (via the `about` or `resource` attribute) you allow other sources to make statements about this image. -- Apart from that, consumers that parse RDF(a) are not necessarily also looking at the HTML, so they wouldn’t notice an "untyped" `img`.